# Reducing an inequality involving an exponential term?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to use `Reduce` to simplify the following inequality.

```
x=1/(1-b1+b2);
FullSimplify[Reduce[x>Exp[b1-b2]&&0<b1<1&&0<b2<1]]
```

When I run this code, I am told "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce." Can this problem be avoided in this particular case?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `With` and `Reduce`:

```
With[{x = 1/(1 - b1 + b2)}, Reduce[x > b1 - b2 && 0 < b1 < 1 && 0 < b2 < 1]]
(*0 < b2 < 1 && 0 < b1 < 1*)
```

First, use `Reduce` as follows:

```
Reduce[x > Exp[b1 - b2] && 0 < b1 < 1 && 0 < b2 < 1, {x, b1, b2}, Reals]
(*(1/E < x <= 1 && 0 < b1 < 1 + Log[x] && b1 - Log[x] < b2 < 1) || (1 < x < E && ((0 < b1 <= Log[x] && 0 < b2 < 1) || (Log[x] < b1 < 1 && b1 - Log[x] < b2 < 1))) || (x >= E && 0 < b1 < 1 && 0 < b2 < 1)*)
```

Then analyze each case, for example:

```
cond1 = With[{x = 1/(1 - b1 + b2)}, Exists[Variables[x], 1/E < x <= 1 && 0 < b1 < 1 + Log[x] && b1 - Log[x] < b2 < 1]]
```

Using `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[1/(1 - b1 + b2) > Exp[b1 - b2] && 0 < b1 < 1 && 0 < b2 < 1, {b1, b2}]
(*{{b1 -> 25967303/259782103, b2 -> 25653364/36848105}}*)
```

We check that the first condition `cond1` is `True`:

```
cond1/.{b1 -> 25967303/259782103, b2 -> 25653364/36848105}
(*True*)
```

Comment: I accidentally left out the exponential on the right hand side of the inequality. This exponential term is what is giving me an error and I am wondering if there is a way around this problem. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It is recommended to analyze by cases to test which inequalities satisfy your original inequality.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, friendly @BiologistLearningMath, it's a pleasure to help. :-)