# Reducing an inequality with a complicated Log term?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I am trying to symbolically `Reduce` the following (admittedly complicated) inequality:

```
x = (b1 - 
     b2) (1 - b1 + 
      b2)^2 ((b1 - b2) ((b1 - b2)^2 + (2 - 3 b1 + 3 b2) bMax) + 
     2 (1 - b1 + b2)^2 bMax Log[1 - b1 + b2]);

FullSimplify[Reduce[x > 0 && 0 < b1 < b2 < bMax && bMax > 0]]
```

When I run this code, I am told "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to reduce."

The workaround described in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273902/reducing-an-inequality-involving-an-exponential-term) post is not working for me, as I still ultimately receive the same error when evaluating an inequality involving the Log term. Is there any other way reduce the inequality symbolically (i.e., analytically)?

Comment: There appears to be an extra "> 0" at the end of your definition of $x$.

Comment: @LouisB Whoops, sorry, I fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if a single `Reduce` call will do it, but I can help OP with analyzing this problem.

A simple observation is that OPs expression only depends on the difference `b2-b1`. Therefore, let us replace this by a new symbol that I will call `u`. The assumptions that OP has given imply `0<u<bMax` that we will use below.

Replace `b2-b1` with `u` as follows:

```
x2=x/.{b2->b1+u}//Simplify
(* u (1+u)^2 (u^3+bMax u (2+3 u)-2 bMax (1+u)^2 Log[1+u]) *)
```

Note that the expression does not contain `b1` and does not contain `b2`. The first factor is positive, `u>0`. The second factor is positive, `(1+u)^2>0`. Therefore the inequality `x2>0` is equivalent to the third factor being positive. Let me use `Reduce` for just that problem:

```
reduce[bMax_] := Reduce[u^3+bMax u (2+3 u)-2 bMax (1+u)^2 Log[1+u]>0 && 0<u<bMax];
```

The idea is that if we provide a number for `bMax`, then there us only one variable left, namely `u`, and then `Reduce` is much more likely to produce something useful. Here are two examples

```
reduce[3/2]
(* 0 < u < 3/2 *)

reduce[2163/1000]
(* False *)
```

In the first example, all `u` are allowed, meaning all `u` that satisfy the obvious inequality `0<u<bMax`. In the second example, no `u` is allowed. By experimenting a little bit, the following picture emerges:

- If `0 < bMax <= 3/2`, then all `u` that satisfy `0<u<bMax` are allowed.
- If `bMax >= threshold`, then no `u` is allowed. The threshold is near `2.16258...`, a symbolic expression is given below.
- If `3/2 < bMax < threshold`, then the variable `u` must lie in an interval of the form `lower[bMax] < u < bMax`. The function `lower[bMax]` is defined below.

Here is an example from the third case:

```
reduce[2]
(* 1.57...<u<2 *)
```

The lower bound is some `Root` object.

Code to produce the lower bound directly would be

```
lower[bMax_]:=u/.First[Solve[{u^3+bMax u (2+3 u)-2 bMax (1+u)^2 Log[1+u]==0,u>0},u]];
```

The `threshold` mentioned above is that value `bMax` where `lower[threshold]` becomes equal to `threshold`. Explicit code for this is

```
threshold=u/.First[Solve[{With[{bMax=u},
   u^3+bMax u (2+3 u)-2 bMax (1+u)^2 Log[1+u]]==0,u>0}]]
(* 2.16... given as a Root object*)
```

**Note.** I did not provide a proof of each step, especially when I wrote down the three cases above. Some more work would be required to prove these things in detail. OP may also want to try to run `reduce[bMax]` with `bMax` symbolic, maybe it will return something useful.

---

**Plot.** Here is a plot for `3/2 < bMax < threshold`:

[image]

The yellow curve is not linear but it is approximately linear:

```
(* a linear approximation to lower[bMax] *)
lowerApproximate[bMax_]:=threshold*(bMax-3/2)/(threshold-3/2);
```

This was generated using

```
With[{aux=u^3/(-u (2+3 u)+2 (1+u)^2 Log[1+u])},ParametricPlot[{{aux,aux},{aux,u}},{u,0,threshold},AspectRatio->1,AxesLabel->{"bMax"},PlotLegends->{"bMax","lower[bMax]"}]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was extremely helpful